# LocalDateTime in IntelliJ IDEA Kotlin shows as unresolved reference

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

java.time seems to be missing entirely. The code I'm trying it in is a simple

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(LocalDateTime.now())
}
```

Seems like I am missing something fundamental, but all I have been doing is following along in a tutorial and it just worked for the tutor.

Comment: Kotlin compiles to Java 6 by default, which doesn't have LocalDateTime. You need to set it to Java 8

Comment: @D3xter, as far as I can tell, you don't need to set the JDK 8 target to use the class; just compiling against JDK 8+ is enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) class has only been introduced in Java SE 8, so you need to compile your project against JDK 8 or newer.

Make sure that:

- You have an installed JDK 8 or newer;
- Your project is compiled against this JDK 8+.

  (In IntelliJ IDEA, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> → *Project* → *Project SDK*; other build systems should be set up separately)

With the JDK configured correctly, the code should run fine as-is: [(demo)](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS42LjIwIiwiY29kZSI6ImltcG9ydCBqYXZhLnRpbWUuTG9jYWxEYXRlVGltZVxuXG5mdW4gbWFpbihhcmdzOiBBcnJheTxTdHJpbmc+KSB7XG4gICAgcHJpbnRsbihMb2NhbERhdGVUaW1lLm5vdygpKVxufSIsInBsYXRmb3JtIjoiamF2YSIsImFyZ3MiOiIiLCJqc0NvZGUiOiIifQ==)